# Undeclared identifier that is declared?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, undeclared-identifier

I am making an app where if the webpage doesnt load, it gives an error and returns to the previous screen. However, in doing this, after all the code, get an undeclared identifier

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIAlertView *cats = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"**Read this first!**" 
                                                   message:@"Thank you for ..." 
                                                  delegate:nil 
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [cats show];
    [catscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [catscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,4800)];
    [catscroll setPagingEnabled:NO];
    [catform loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.petfinder.com/s/showPage.do?siteId=76333&pageId=7133416&shelterId=MA84&navigateToPage=Adopt%20Pets"]]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)doPop
{
    [cats dissmissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIAlertView *noconnectcatform = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check your connection!" 
                                                               message:@"Cannot connect to FPP Servers.\nPlease check your Internet Connection\nYou may not proceed until you are connected via a cellular network." 
                                                              delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [noconnectcatform show];
}
```

as you can see in this image. If the webpage doesnt load it activates doPop, which returns the view and displays a message. However, this is throwing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS because, as you can see, under the viewDidLoad method, there is another message that plays. The app is getting confused and crashing. I tried to fix this by dismissing the alert in the doPop method, however it is strangely giving me this error. I may be misunderstanding, but isn't the alertview defined where it says "UIAlertView *cats"? why does it say that it is not defined in the doPop method? Please help!

Comment: Copy paste your code using the code format here in stack overflow, otherwise its too troublesome to check for us. Actually never mind, in this case your image is high enough quality to read.

Comment: Alright: Couln't figure out the StackOverflow format, but here is the pastie.org link: http://pastie.org/4117873

Comment: try setting the delegate of the message that there was an error to nil.

Comment: that didn't fix the error. You meant change UIAlertView *cats....................delegate:self   to UIAlertView *cats....................delegate:nil,   right?

Comment: Here is the .h just in case: http://pastie.org/4117942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `cats` is defined locally to `viewDidLoad`.  The scope of the variable does not extend beyond the method, thus `doPop` has no idea what cats is.

Move `cats` to be defined in the .h file as a member/class variable.

This means you'll need to remove the `UIAlertView *` from within `viewDidLoad` and just reference cats (as is, you are defining another variable scoped to `viewDidLoad`).

You have a typo in the method called in `doPop`  The method is `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];`  You have `dissmissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];`

Also, you only need `IBOutlet` defined with the `@property`

Comment: That's what I actually was starting to think. Thank you for clarifying! I did try to define it globally, but it gave me a different error. let me get it up.

Comment: I updated the pastie links in the comments below to my new code. I now get this error: No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the sector 'dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated

Comment: Oops! let me read your updates, ignore the previous comments.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the actual problem, its a common practice to declare an uialertview locally and just show it, since it will work and use its delegate as long as its visible on screen.

Comment: I have never defined anything as a member/class variable. What would the code be specifically for that? Also, where would I put the message if I removed it (or reference as you put it?)

Comment: You actually have the variable correctly defined in the .h file.  Can you post a screenshot of the error please?

Comment: My edit contains the problem, it was a typo in the method name, dismiss is not spelled dissmiss

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so if i were you i would simply show the error message on the view that failed to load, then use the default cancel action to pop this view (This is the most common practice)

Alternatively, if you really wanna show the message in the other view you have to make that view display the error message. there are several ways to do this but id still go with the first option. (I could tell you how if you really wanna take this approach)

Edit: If you just want that error to go away, add before "Implementation" in your .m file

```
@interface CatForm ()
{
    UIAlertView *cats;
}

@end
```

and change

```
UIAlertView *cats = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"**Read this first!**" 
                                                                  message:@"Thank you for considering to adopt a cat from our shelter. PLEASE READ THIS FORM CAREFULLY.\n\nThis on-line form is intended to assist you in selecting a cat that is suitable for you, your family, and your lifestyle.\n\nThe Friends of the Plymouth Pound have established guidelines and policies that must be met in order for your pre-screening application to be approved.\n\nThe information you provide is essential to facilitate the application review process.\n\nIn order to be considered for adoption by the Friends of the Plymouth Pound, you must:\n\n\n*Be at least 18 years old.\n\n*Provide all the applicable information requested below.\n\n**Note, any data field marked with an asterisk character (*) must be filled in. Incomplete application forms will not be considered for review and will be denied automatically.**\n\n*Understand that this is a pre-screening form.\n\n\nThe Friends of the Plymouth Pound will contact you and approve you if, and only if, all requirements have been met.\n\nUpon review of your pre-screening application, you will be contacted by the Friends of the Plymouth Pound to notify you if your application has been accepted and if further information is needed. \n\n\n**Please note that we do contact all personal references and veterinarians, and we must speak with them personally. In addition, in some cases, a pre-adoption home visit may also be required.**\n\nIn the event that your pre-screening application has been not been approved, we will notify you of same.\n\n\nTHE BOARD OF DIRECTORS OF THE FRIENDS OF THE PLYMOUTH POUND RESERVES THE RIGHT TO DENY ANY PRE-APPLICATION BASED ON THE ORGANIZATION'S ESTABLISHED STANDARDS AND POLICIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, INCOMPLETE INFORMATION, NON-DISCLOSURE OR OMISSION OF PERTINENT FACTS, AND NON-COMPLIANCE WITH ACCEPTED STANDARDS.\n\n\nUpon approval of your application and transfer of the animal, you will be charged a $150.00 adoption fee per cat.\n\n\nWe are an all-volunteer organization. Due to the high volume of applications, we ask that you be patient in waiting for a reply. Please do not submit duplicate applications or separate requests for response. Doing this will not accelerate the review process in any way." 
                                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

for

```
cats = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"**Read this first!**" 
                                                                  message:@"Thank you for considering to adopt a cat from our shelter. PLEASE READ THIS FORM CAREFULLY.\n\nThis on-line form is intended to assist you in selecting a cat that is suitable for you, your family, and your lifestyle.\n\nThe Friends of the Plymouth Pound have established guidelines and policies that must be met in order for your pre-screening application to be approved.\n\nThe information you provide is essential to facilitate the application review process.\n\nIn order to be considered for adoption by the Friends of the Plymouth Pound, you must:\n\n\n*Be at least 18 years old.\n\n*Provide all the applicable information requested below.\n\n**Note, any data field marked with an asterisk character (*) must be filled in. Incomplete application forms will not be considered for review and will be denied automatically.**\n\n*Understand that this is a pre-screening form.\n\n\nThe Friends of the Plymouth Pound will contact you and approve you if, and only if, all requirements have been met.\n\nUpon review of your pre-screening application, you will be contacted by the Friends of the Plymouth Pound to notify you if your application has been accepted and if further information is needed. \n\n\n**Please note that we do contact all personal references and veterinarians, and we must speak with them personally. In addition, in some cases, a pre-adoption home visit may also be required.**\n\nIn the event that your pre-screening application has been not been approved, we will notify you of same.\n\n\nTHE BOARD OF DIRECTORS OF THE FRIENDS OF THE PLYMOUTH POUND RESERVES THE RIGHT TO DENY ANY PRE-APPLICATION BASED ON THE ORGANIZATION'S ESTABLISHED STANDARDS AND POLICIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, INCOMPLETE INFORMATION, NON-DISCLOSURE OR OMISSION OF PERTINENT FACTS, AND NON-COMPLIANCE WITH ACCEPTED STANDARDS.\n\n\nUpon approval of your application and transfer of the animal, you will be charged a $150.00 adoption fee per cat.\n\n\nWe are an all-volunteer organization. Due to the high volume of applications, we ask that you be patient in waiting for a reply. Please do not submit duplicate applications or separate requests for response. Doing this will not accelerate the review process in any way." 
                                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

In the View Did Load

Comment: You are missing the point.  He is looking to manually dismiss the UIAlertView

Comment: Here is the way the app in the user's hands would work.    If the user has no internet connection, the app would send an error message (doesn't matter which screen) but boot the user to the previous screen (The adoption form pick screen)

Comment: @SamGehly just delete the cats dismisswithbutton click bla bla, you dont need it, without a delegate and if you dont override the behavior it automatically dismisses when the user presses the cancel button.

Comment: @obuseme you just dont downvote answers for that reason, the final goal of sam is clear, The solution i post here is to solve the FIRST issue with the exec bad access, which he tried to solve in his way but it was not necessary.

Comment: I down voted because your answer was off topic and not relevant to the real issue at hand.

Comment: @LuisOscar  That worked, however I wish to not have the *cats  message (The long one) appear if there is no internet connection. Thanks though! I hope you two can work together to find a solution, not fight :D

Comment: @SamGehly the approach you took is not what would be considered the correct one, which is what i was trying to help you with.